# Is Lorenz curve really a PP plot?

Tags: probability, distributions, mathematical-statistics, lorenz-curve

Kendall (1945) defines the curve of concentration (AFAIU, this is a synonym for Lorenz curve) as a parametric curve
$$
\left\{ \begin{aligned}F(x) & =\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)\mathrm{d}t\\
G(x) & =\frac{1}{\mu}\int_{-\infty}^{x}tf(t)\mathrm{d}t,
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$
where $F(x)$ is the CDF of a random variable $X$ with finite mean $\mu=\int_{\mathbb{R}}tf(t)\mathrm{d}t; x\in\mathrm{supp}\,X$. By the way, the expression for $G(x)$ really looks like a ratio of two expectations (times the probability---thanks, [@stats_model](https://stats.stackexchange.com/users/188356/stats-model)): $$G(x)=\frac{\mathsf{E}(X\mid X\leq x)\mathsf{P}(X \leq x)}{\mathsf{E}X}.$$

On the other hand, a few sources ([here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lorenz_curve#Definition_and_calculation), [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/66749/cumulative-cumulative-plot-or-visualizing-a-lorenz-curve#comment128844_66749)) refer to Lorenz curve as “PP plots” of $X$ against a hypothetical uniform distribution---which makes sense, since then its interpretation as representing inequality of the wealth distribution becomes apparent (wealth is equally distributed if x% of the population own x% of it). This, however, contradicts the first definition:
$$\left\{ \begin{aligned}F(x) & =\mathrm{CDF}_{X}(x)=\int_{-\infty}^{x}f(t)\mathrm{d}t\\
G(x) & =\mathrm{CDF}_{\mathrm{U}(a,b)}(x).
\end{aligned}
\right.$$

I find it hard to match the two definitions, and it seems like referring to Lorenz curves as “PP plots” is wrong. Or isn't it?

---

Kendall (1945): Kendall M.G., The Advanced Theory of Statistics, Volume I, 1945

Comment: Still trying to find an answer to the main question, but in the meantime, I should point out that your interpretation of $G(x)$ as the ratio of two expectatiosn is slightly wrong: $G(x) = \frac{\mathbb E[X|X\leq x]\mathrm{Pr}[X\leq x]}{\mathbb E[X]}$. Interestingly, your expression is the right interpretation of $\frac{G(x)}{F(x)}$.

Comment: @stats_model, you're right, thanks for pointing this out 

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer my own question, the Lorenz curve is indeed a PP-plot, but in a different sense than I originally imagined.  In particular, we can use various theoretical distributions to model the income distribution, but the resulting plot is always a comparison of $\mathrm{U}(0,1)$ CDF against a distribution with support $[0,1]$.  In case the wealth is equally distributed, this distribution is also uniform, meaning the PP plot is a straight line.

First of all, it may be more productive to think about Lorenz curves in a non-probabilistic sense.  Levine (1970) gives a formal description of Lorenz curves in the original sense as a way to quantify the income inequality, which I'm summarising below:

---

Let $t\in[0,\infty)$ denote the income, $f(t)$ the income density over people, i.e. $f(t)\mathrm{d} t$ approximately equals to the
number of people earning income in the range $(t,t+\mathrm{d} t)$. To reiterate, the integral of $f(t)$ over its domain is not equal to 1, so it's not a PDF, rather it is the total number of people:
$$
f_{0}=\int_{0}^{\infty}f(t)\mathrm{d} t.
$$
The total income earned by the people who earn income in the range
$(t,t+\mathrm{d} t)$ is $t\,f(t)\mathrm{d} t$. Then the total income of the population
is $\int_{0}^{\infty}tf(t)\mathrm{d} t$, and the average income per person
is
$$
\mu=\frac{1}{f_{0}}\int_{0}^{\infty}tf(t)\mathrm{d} t.
$$
Then the following two quantities are compared:

- The fraction of the population earning $z$ or less:
  $$
  F(z)=\frac{1}{f_{0}}\int_{0}^{z}f(t)\mathrm{d} t
  $$
- The fraction of the total income earned by the people with income
  $z$ or less:
  $$
  G(z)=\frac{\int_{0}^{z}tf(t)\mathrm{d} t}{\int_{0}^{\infty}tf(t)\mathrm{d} t}=\frac{1}{f_{0}}\frac{1}{\mu}\int_{0}^{z}tf(t)\mathrm{d} t.
  $$

The *Lorenz curve* is a parametric curve given by
$$
\left\{ \begin{aligned}x & =F(z)\\
y & =G(z).
\end{aligned}
\right.
$$

---

We could've used normalised density
$\tilde{f}(t)=f(t)/f_{0}$ with $\int_{0}^{\infty}\tilde{f}(t)\mathrm{d} t=1$.
I guess in this case it is correct to say that $f(t)$ is the density of the "income" random variable.  Below $f(t)$ has unit integral over the domain.

The Lorenz curve equations can be implicitised using a suitable change of variable (and the inverse function rule), i.e. let $F(z)=p$; then $z=F^{-1}(p)$ and
$$
G(z)=L(p)=\frac{1}{\mu}\int_{0}^{p}F^{-1}(u)\,\mathrm{d} u.
$$

The equation above gives a reason to interpret the Lorenz curve as a PP-plot of $F(z)=p=\mathrm{cdf}_{\mathrm{U}(0,1)}(p)$ against a variable $Y$ with density $F^{-1}(p)/\mu$.  Indeed, the curve is a graph in $[0,1]\times [0,1]$. By construction, $\mathrm{supp}Y = [0,1]$.    Moreover, since $z \mathrm{d}u$ has the meaning of "$\mathrm{d}u$ proportion of the population earns $z$",  $$\int_{0}^{1}F^{-1}(u)\mathrm{d} u=\int_{0}^{1}z(u)\mathrm{d} u=\mu$$ is the average income population.  The wealth is equally distributed if the fraction of the population
earning $z$ or less equals the fraction of the total income earned
by this group. In other words, $F(z)\equiv G(z)$, or, equivalently,
$L(p)=p,$ and the Lorenz curve is a straight line.  This implies the density $F^{-1}(p)/\mu$ is constant.  In fact, because $\mathrm{supp}Y = [0,1]$, $F^{-1}(u)/\mu=1$ and $z\equiv\mu$ (the only possible income for everybody is $\mu$).  Implying in the "ideal" case $Y \sim \mathrm{U}(0,1)$.

I think this makes some sense.  Below is another way of looking at the "ideal" case.

---

Interestingly, equal wealth distribution is not described by the uniform distribution of income. For simplicity, suppose $f(t)=1/\theta$, $t\in[0,\theta]$ (a uniform density with $a=0$). Then
\begin{align*}
F(z) & =\int_{0}^{z}f(t)\mathrm{d} t=\int_{0}^{z}1/\theta\,\mathrm{d} t=\frac{z}{\theta},\quad z\in[0,\theta]\\
\mu & =\int_{0}^{\infty}tf(t)\mathrm{d} t=\frac{1}{\theta}\int_{0}^{\theta}t\mathrm{d} t=\frac{\theta}{2}.\\
G(z) & =\frac{1}{\mu}\int_{0}^{z}tf(t)\mathrm{d} t=\frac{2}{\theta}\frac{1}{\theta}\int_{0}^{z}t\mathrm{d} t=\frac{z^{2}}{\theta^{2}}=F^{2}(z)\\
F^{-1}(p) & =\theta p\\
L(p) & =\frac{1}{\mu}\int_{0}^{p}F^{-1}(u)\mathrm{d} u=\frac{2}{\theta}\frac{\theta}{2}p^{2}=p^{2}.
\end{align*}

In fact the case of equal wealth distribution corresponds to a Dirac's delta distribution. In other words,
$$
F(z)=G(z)\ \forall z\in[0,\infty)\iff\int_{0}^{z}f(t)\mathrm{d} t=\frac{1}{\mu}\int_{0}^{z}tf(t)\mathrm{d} t\iff f(t)=\frac{1}{\mu}tf(t)\ \forall t\in0:z,
$$
which implies that $f(t)$ is the Dirac's delta
$$
\delta_{\mu}(t)=\begin{cases}
0 & t\neq\mu\\
1 & t=\mu.
\end{cases}
$$
Then
$$
F(z)=\begin{cases}
0 & z<\mu\\
1 & z\geq\mu
\end{cases},\quad G(z)=\begin{cases}
0 & z<\mu\\
\mu/\mu=1 & z\geq\mu.
\end{cases}
$$

Therefore, the Lorenz curve is $\{(0, 0), (1, 1)\}$.

---

Levine (1970): Levine, Singer -- The mathematical relation between the income density function and the measurement of income inequality (1970)